# How to avoid RecursionLimit error when using Interpretation formatting?

Tags: function-construction, warning-messages, recursion, format

I am trying to define a function that has similar behavior as `Indexed`. Here is the code

```
Format[me : f[a_, i__]] := Interpretation[Subscript[a, i], me];
f[a_ + b_, i__] := f[a, i] + f[b, i];
```

For example, `f[a + b, 1]` will give

[image: a1+b1]

as expected. However, if I try `?f` to view the code, I will run into the RecursionLimit error. The question is how to appropriately define the format to avoid this error, while still give the desired subscript formatting behavior?

Comment: Related but not AFAICT a solution in this case: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4112299/618728

Comment: I don't have more time to look at this (it's Christmas!) but I am suspicious of a bug in `Information` here.  I'll try to figure this out later if it's not solved by then.

Comment: You can view the code with `Definition @ f`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use:

```
f /: MakeBoxes[f[a_, i__], form:StandardForm] := With[
    {s = MakeBoxes[Subscript[a, i], form]},
    InterpretationBox[s, f[a, i]]
]
```

instead.